# MY SQL unmet dependencies. I am trying to install but can't not even remove it. How can I make it correct?

Tags: mysql, dependencies

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdbusmenu-gtk4 libllvm3.8 libmircommon5 libmysqlclient20 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libqmi-glib1
  libqpdf17 libreadline5 libsnapd-glib1 libterm-readkey-perl linux-signed-image-generic mariadb-common ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,831 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 207681 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.7.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.7, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this file if you are sure to downgrade as installer says:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag
```

Then try again:

```
sudo apt -f install

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```